# Drools: Not able to update Collection Objects properly

Tags: drools

I am using Drools 5.5.0 Final Expert to do Alarm Co-relation. I was trying to collect the facts in to the ArrayList collection. My drl file will look like below. From the Rule I calling an Java method to access the collected facts.

```
rule "Rule [Alarm Collection]"
no-loop
   when
    $alarmColl : ArrayList() from collect(Alarm 
         ( 
            JustInserted == true;
         ))

    then
    // act on $alarmColl
end
```

while in my Java code I am loop through the collection to set an attribute of the Alarm Object. But while I am trying to set this attribute in the collection, the collection is getting updated and indexes are changed. Due to which all the objects are not updated. Even I tried using the iterator to access the ArrayList collection. Still the same issue.

```
while(index < alarmColl.size()){
            Alarm alarmObj=alarmColl.get(index)

            if(alarmObj.isJustInserted()) {
                alarmObj.setJustInserted(false);
                theScenario.getSession().update(alarmObj);
            }
            index++;
}
```

How can I update the objects in collection without changing the index or any other way to achieve this.

Comment: This has been answered on Nabble, via the Drools User List

Comment: the missing link: http://drools-moved.46999.n3.nabble.com/Problem-with-Collection-td4029219.html